# What is causing this GAE error message?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm migrating a webapp to python 2.7 with GAE and this error message appears:

```
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 129, in _StartResponse     raise InvalidResponseError('headers must be str') InvalidResponseError: headers must be str
```

What does it mean? I saw [someone else had the same problem](http://www.renderpaz.com/2011/10/app-engine-switched-to-python-27-hrd.html) but I'm not in the same situation. Is there something with my render method from the basehandler class?

My code:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    facebook = None
    user = None
    csrf_protect = True


    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
            self._current_user = None
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(
                self.request.cookies, conf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, conf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
        logging.debug("logging cookie"+str(cookie))
            if cookie:
                # Store a local instance of the user data so we don't need
                # a round-trip to Facebook on every request
                user = FBUser.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                logging.debug("user "+str(user))
                logging.debug("username "+str(user.name))

                if not user:
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    user = User(key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                                user_id=str(profile["id"]),
                                name=profile["name"],
                                profile_url=profile["link"],
                                access_token=cookie["access_token"])
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                self._current_user = user
        return self._current_user

    def initialize(self, request, response):


        super(BaseHandler, self).initialize(request, response)

        try:
            self.init_facebook()
            self.init_csrf()
            self.response.headers[u'P3P'] = u'CP=HONK'  # iframe cookies in IE
        except Exception, ex:
            self.log_exception(ex)
            raise

    def handle_exception(self, ex, debug_mode):


        self.log_exception(ex)
        self.render(u'error', trace=traceback.format_exc(),
                    debug_mode=debug_mode)

    def log_exception(self, ex):


        msg = (str(ex) or ex.__class__.__name__) + u': \n' \
            + traceback.format_exc()
        if isinstance(ex, urlfetch.DownloadError) or isinstance(ex,
                DeadlineExceededError) or isinstance(ex, CsrfException) \
            or isinstance(ex, taskqueue.TransientError):
            logging.warn(msg)
        else:
            logging.error(msg)

    def set_cookie(
        self,
        name,
        value,
        expires=None,
        ):


        if value is None:
            value = 'deleted'
            expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=-50000)
        jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        jar[name] = value
        jar[name]['path'] = u'/'
        if expires:
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.timedelta):
                expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
                expires = expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
            jar[name]['expires'] = expires
        self.response.headers.add_header(*jar.output().split(u': ', 1))

    def render(self, name, **data):


        if not data:
            data = {}
        data[u'js_conf'] = json.dumps({u'appId': conf.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                u'canvasName': conf.FACEBOOK_CANVAS_NAME,
                u'userIdOnServer'
                : (self.user.user_id if self.user else None)})
        data[u'logged_in_user'] = self.user
        data[u'message'] = self.get_message()
        data[u'csrf_token'] = self.csrf_token
        data[u'canvas_name'] = conf.FACEBOOK_CANVAS_NAME
        self.response.out.write(template.render(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                'templates', name + '.html'), str(data)))

    def init_facebook(self):


        facebook = Facebook()
        user = None

        # initial facebook request comes in as a POST with a signed_request

        if u'signed_request' in self.request.POST:
            facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.get('signed_request'
                    ))

            # we reset the method to GET because a request from facebook with a
            # signed_request uses POST for security reasons, despite it
            # actually being a GET. in webapp causes loss of request.POST data.

            self.request.method = u'GET'
            self.set_cookie('u', facebook.user_cookie,
                            datetime.timedelta(minutes=1440))
        elif 'u' in self.request.cookies:
            facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.cookies.get('u'))

        # try to load or create a user object

        if facebook.user_id:
            user = User.get_by_key_name(facebook.user_id)
            if user:

                # update stored access_token

                if facebook.access_token and facebook.access_token \
                    != user.access_token:
                    user.access_token = facebook.access_token
                    user.put()

                # refresh data if we failed in doing so after a realtime ping

                if user.dirty:
                    user.refresh_data()

                # restore stored access_token if necessary

                if not facebook.access_token:
                    facebook.access_token = user.access_token

            if not user and facebook.access_token:
                me = facebook.api(u'/me', {u'fields': _USER_FIELDS})
                try:
                    friends = [user[u'id'] for user in me[u'friends'
                               ][u'data']]
                    user = User(
                        key_name=facebook.user_id,
                        user_id=facebook.user_id,
                        friends=friends,
                        access_token=facebook.access_token,
                        name=me[u'name'],
                        email=me.get(u'email'),
                        picture=me[u'picture'],
                        )
                    user.put()
                except KeyError, ex:
                    pass  # ignore if can't get the minimum fields

        self.facebook = facebook
        self.user = user

    def init_csrf(self):


        self.csrf_token = self.request.cookies.get(u'c')
        if not self.csrf_token:
            self.csrf_token = str(uuid4())[:8]
            self.set_cookie('c', self.csrf_token)
        if self.request.method == u'POST' and self.csrf_protect \
            and self.csrf_token != self.request.POST.get(u'_csrf_token'
                ):
            raise CsrfException(u'Missing or invalid CSRF token.')

    def set_message(self, **obj):


        self.set_cookie('m',
                        (base64.b64encode(json.dumps(obj)) if obj else None))

    def get_message(self):


        message = self.request.cookies.get(u'm')
        if message:
            self.set_message()  # clear the current cookie
            return json.loads(base64.b64decode(message))

import random
from google.appengine.api import files, images
class CyberFazeHandler(BaseHandler):

    """Handle the home page that renders 3 random images"""
    def get_random_image(self, category):
        """get a random image O(1) by category"""
        q = FileInfo.all()
        q.filter('category =', category)
        q.filter('randomvalue >=', random.random())
        return q.get()

    def get(self):
        logging.info('get ')
        """build up the random face from the random body """
    try:             
          eyes_image = self.get_random_image(category='eyes')
          nose_image = self.get_random_image(category='nose')
          mouth_image = self.get_random_image(category='mouth')
          logging.info('set mouth id '+str(eyes_image.blob.key()))
          eyes_data = blobstore.fetch_data(eyes_image.blob.key(), 0, 50000)
          eyes_img = images.Image(image_data=eyes_dat
          nose_data = blobstore.fetch_data(nose_image.blob.key(), 0, 50000)
          nose_img = images.Image(image_data=nose_data)
          logging.info('eyes image ')
          mouth_data = blobstore.fetch_data(mouth_image.blob.key(),0, 50000)
          mouth_img = images.Image(image_data=mouth_data)
          minimum = int(min(eyes_img.width, nose_img.width, mouth_img.width))
          eyes_url = images.get_serving_url(str(eyes_image.blob.key()), size=minimum)
          nose_url = images.get_serving_url(str(nose_image.blob.key()), size=minimum)
          mouth_url = images.get_serving_url(str(mouth_image.blob.key()), size=minimum)


          self.render('cyberfaze', minimum=minimum, eyes_image=eyes_image, eyes_url=eyes_url, nose_image=nose_image, nose_url=nose_url, mouth_image=mouth_image, mouth_url=mouth_url, form_url=blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload'),)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.response.headers[u'P3P'] = u'CP=HONK'`

Try passing strings here instead of casting to unicode.